# How to check whether file copying is in progress?

Tags: c#, file-copying

Is there any way to know whether a file is "being written" or "completed copying" in C# without trying to open the file?

Comment: please provide more details like whether you are copying the file or is it done by some other application. Did you check out the `FileWatcher`.

Comment: hi Saravanan .
Thank you for your reply..
Ya Files will be copied manually.
But some service will be keep on monitoring the folder and enter an entry into db if new file is found with combination of (File Name, Size ).

Whats happening is,
When File is being copied, The service getting file size  as 0 and after file copy is done Service getting actual size of file.

so Service is inserting 2 entries in DB with 0 size and with actual size  for One File .

Answer (score 0):

The FileInfo class does not support these callback. Perhaps you can write your own class to do this. Take a look http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the process which is working with file, example - if you have initiated the copying and trying to find out if the file is completed copying or not?

if the expectation is some other process is trying to write the file and you are expecting to capture the status of it? - In this case technically not possible as the file system will not give handle unless the file is completely written.

If the file already exists and another process is writing into file - it will be only dirty ready to get the contents.  there is technically no LOCK on the file unless process actually tries to save / overrite.

Please be more specific on the question

Comment: Thank you for the reply .

Yes , Required is second one.

i.e, if the expectation is some other process is trying to write the file and you are expecting to capture the status of it? - In this case technically not possible as the file system will not give handle unless the file is completely written.

Comment: Exact issue is : One process will be copying the file to a folder.Another Process will see that file is in that folder and will try to transfer to some other location.

Comment: What we require is when the file is being copied , it shouldn't be listed / found to the another process which is trying to transfer to  another location.